# How Can I handle an UITabBarItem clicked twice consecutive and dismiss segues?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

My UITabBarController caching everything about before selected item, It's nice but I want to dismiss each segue presented by me When I have clicked displayed view's item, twice consecutive same page.

How and What I need to do to provide this case? Detailed answer for solution It would be great.

Comment: you can use pop to root view controller \

Comment: But how in Swift, Need I embed in Navigation Controller to all my views to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tabbarControler delegate method

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
if (alreadyPushed){
return false
}
return true
}
```